# Sklearn Fit Linear Regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I have this problem:

```
  regression.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 2.9  5.1  3.2  4.5  8.2  6.8  1.3 10.5  3.   2.2  5.9  6.   3.7  3.2
  9.   2.   1.1  7.1  4.9  4. ].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead" in sklearn/python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638641/how-to-fix-valueerror-expected-2d-array-got-1d-array-instead-in-sklearn-pyth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shared your source code but here's my 2 cents:

If you have a hardcoded array, instead of 1D array:

```
array=[ 2.9, 5.1, 3.2, 4.5, 8.2, 6.8, 1.3, 10.5, 3., 2.2, 5.9, 6., 3.7, 3.2, 9., 2., 1.1, 7.1, 4.9, 4.]
```

use a 2D array:

```
array=[[ 2.9, 5.1, 3.2, 4.5, 8.2, 6.8, 1.3, 10.5, 3., 2.2, 5.9, 6., 3.7, 3.2, 9., 2., 1.1, 7.1, 4.9, 4.]]
```

If you want to convert a 1D array to 2D array then simply use numpy's [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) function. For example,

```
>>> test_array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> test_array
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> test_array = test_array.reshape(1, -1)
>>> test_array
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Comment: It's rather unlikely that their sample size is 1, and they'll probably want `.reshape(-1, 1)`