# Best fit/simple linear regression for data set in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-regression, finance

I have 1000+ .txt files with two columns, one being dates, the other being prices (for stocks), with each file named after the ticker for the stock. I want to find a best fit line for the data to figure out whether it is trending positively, negatively, or flat. I figured I could do this by finding the slope of the best fit line. Does anyone know how I could code this?

So Far I have:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import os as os
import seaborn as sns
from statistics import mean
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import metrics
%matplotlib inline

filelist = os.listdir(r'InsertFilePath')

filepath = r'InsertFilePath'

dic1 = {}
#Uploads files to a Dictionary with filename(ticker) being the keys and the Data being the values
for file in filelist:
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath + file,sep='\t')
    dic1[file]= df


#renames Columns to Dates and Prices
for key,value in dic1.items():
     value.rename(columns={value.columns[0]:'Dates',value.columns[1]:'Prices'},inplace=True)

x = df['Dates']
y = df['Prices']
LinearRegression().fit(x,y)
```

But for the last three lines, I get an error because the Dates are in string form. I tired doing int(df['Dates]) but that doesn't work either. I'm pretty new to python so forgive me.

Comment: I think you should switch the price to X and dates to Y

Comment: @chatax  got the following error: ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 50.6138  49.2798  49.3017 ... 147.24   146.12   145.0558].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638641/how-to-fix-valueerror-expected-2d-array-got-1d-array-instead-in-sklearn-pyth&ved=2ahUKEwinl-bFm-PnAhVMyaQKHV3mAEcQjjgwAHoECAQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw28TI7cl1nXth59vTbcnrsI

Comment: Turn the dates into a number. `x = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates']); x = (x-x.min()).dt.total_seconds()`