# Passing single row of dictionary to predict with decision tree model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have this simple decision tree model along with the preprocessing

```
merged_df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Kiwi\Downloads\data set balance.xlsx')

list_object = ['NAMA', 'TARGET', 'NIM']

merged_df['NIM'] = merged_df['NIM'].apply(str)

num_columns = merged_df.select_dtypes(include=['float64']).columns
cat_columns = merged_df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).drop(list_object, axis=1).columns

numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('label', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, num_columns),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, cat_columns)])

X = merged_df.drop(['TARGET','NIM','NAMA','NO.'],1)
y = merged_df['TARGET']

X_train = X
y_train = y

rf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                         ('classifier',tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(
                             class_weight='balanced', criterion='entropy'))])

rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('fitted')

X_test = {'Pendidikan Kewarganegaraan': 'C',
 'Pendidikan Agama dalam TIK': 'A-',
 'Kepemimpinan dan Pengembangan Karakter': 'A-',
 'Bahasa Indonesia untuk TI': 'B-',
 'Matematika Diskrit': 'A-',
 'Pengantar Multimedia': 'A',
 'Algoritma dan Pemrograman': 'B',
 'Rekayasa Perangkat Lunak': 'A',
 'Jaringan Komputer dan Komunikasi': 'A-',
 'Aljabar Linier': 'A-',
 'Struktur Data': 'A-',
 'Sistem Basis Data': 'B',
 'IP_smt1': 2.78,
 'IP_smt2': 3.16,
 'IP_smt3': 2.85,
 'IP_smt4': 3.41,
 'IP_smt5': 2.83,
 'IP_smt6': 3.37,
 'IP_smt7': 3.6,
 'IP_s8': 3.16,
 'IPK': 3.145
}

pred = rf.predict([X_test])
```

I'm trying to pass a single row of dictionary (the X_test) to the model but it returns error saying

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:Reshape your data either 
using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to do it but according to the documentation it said the predict accepts array like input but dict cannot be reshape too. Is there any way to fix this or this is not possible?

[the data if you'd like to see](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jZ7rNxQS-anBVKuV_UWICjj5CpgkFAl8iPrGL3K6Jfs/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by simply adding bracket to the X_test

```
X_test = [
{'Pendidikan Kewarganegaraan': 'C',
 'Pendidikan Agama dalam TIK': 'A-',
 'Kepemimpinan dan Pengembangan Karakter': 'A-',
 'Bahasa Indonesia untuk TI': 'B-',
 'Matematika Diskrit': 'A-',
 'Pengantar Multimedia': 'A',
 'Algoritma dan Pemrograman': 'B',
 'Rekayasa Perangkat Lunak': 'A',
 'Jaringan Komputer dan Komunikasi': 'A-',
 'Aljabar Linier': 'A-',
 'Struktur Data': 'A-',
 'Sistem Basis Data': 'B',
 'IP_smt1': 2.78,
 'IP_smt2': 3.16,
 'IP_smt3': 2.85,
 'IP_smt4': 3.41,
 'IP_smt5': 2.83,
 'IP_smt6': 3.37,
 'IP_smt7': 3.6,
 'IP_s8': 3.16,
 'IPK': 3.145
}]
```

and then I turn it into `dataframe`

```
X_test = pd.DataFrame(X_test)
```

and pass it to predict. It works

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are currently passing the input of `rf.predict([X_test])` is essentially saying that `[X_test]` is a list with a single row that is your dictionary `X_test`. If you would like to simply pass the values of the dictionary into `rf.predict()` you could iterate the keys of `X_test` and append to a list.

```
    # import at top of module
    import numpy as np 

    list_x = []
    for key in X_test:
        list_x.append(X_test[key])
    
    # convert to array
    array_x = np.array(list_x)

    # reshape
    array_x = np.reshape(array_x, (-1, 1))
    rf.predict(array_x)
```

Edit: I made a mistake and left out parentheses inside the np.reshape() method. Updated to include correct syntax.

Comment: Do you mean `array_x.shape = np.reshape(len(array_x), 1)`? also when passed into predict, it raised error `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: I found a thread that might be helpful. I believe you could literally just use `array_x = np.reshape(array_x, (-1, 1))` and then call `rf.predict(array_x)`. Reshape does not happen 'in place' so you need to update the value. I also updated the syntax for `np.reshape()`. I accidentally left out the first argument. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638641/how-to-fix-valueerror-expected-2d-array-got-1d-array-instead-in-sklearn-pyth/55449672